# error trying to save a jpeg image from sound and zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do the following in Python:
-Take a sound file
-Turn it into a zip file with gzip (gz extension)
-Then save it the jpg extension

This is the code i tried:

```
import gzip

# write compressed file
with gzip.open('sound.wav', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

# read it again
with gzip.open('my_file.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

and I got this error:

```
 f.write(content)
NameError: name 'content' is not defined
```

Can anyone please explain how to fix it?

Comment: well in the code you've shown content isn't defined when you call `f.write(content)` - are you missing some lines?

Comment: oh and please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: i suppose the content is the file 'sound.wav'??

Comment: thanks for fixing the indentation - you still don't show where content is defined before the call to `f.write(content)`

Comment: You have your read and write backwards, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`content` should contain the contents of the file you want to write. Since you never specify a `content` variable, when you get to `f.write(content)`, Python doesn't know what `content` is and throws an error. If `sound.wav` is your `.wav` file, try:

```
In [1]: import gzip

In [2]: with open('sound.wav', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     o = gzip.open('zipped_file.gz', 'wb')
   ...:     o.write(f.read())
   ...:     o.close()
   ...:
   ...:
```

This will write your `zipped_file.gz` file with the contents of `sound.wav` (I ran this on Python 2.6 where `with` wasn't supported with `gzip`, but using `with` statements as you did is better if you are using 2.7+). As for the `jpg` part, I'm not 100% sure I understand - do you just want to resave your `gz` file as a `jpg`? If you want to save them both in the same archive you will not be able to do it with `gzip`, but if you for some reason want to resave to a new archive, I guess you could try this:

```
In [3]: j = gzip.open('my_file.jpg', 'wb')

In [4]: o = gzip.open('zipped_file.gz', 'rb')

In [5]: j.write(o.read())

In [6]: j.close()

In [7]: o.close()
```